# Regular expression 301 redirects does not work

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I have many pages that were previously in the following format:

```
p/example-title.html
```

currently all are in the pattern:

```
example-title
```

I am trying to use the following regex:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^p/(.+?)(-[0-9]+)?$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

but it does not work

**EDIT:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^p/(.+?)(.html)?$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

**EDIT 2:**
I was using blogger and currently I'm using wordpress the domain is the same, so that's why I tried now with `{HTTPS_HOST}`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# BEGIN 301 Redirects
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
Redirect 301 https://www.example.com/p/(.*)\.html$ https://www.example.com/$1
# END 301 Redirects
</IfModule>
```

but it is not working yet

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get everything after the `p` directory and scape the .html, then redirect.

So, the following will get everything between the `p/` and `.html` and will storage on the `$1`, and then will redirect.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^p/(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you are using Wordpress, insert the following just before the Wordpress directives

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^p/(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

[*] Don't forget to renew your permalinks.

Comment: Thanks,  but it's not working, please see: [lRegex 101](https://regex101.com/r/mKEPOV/1)

Comment: Have you tried on your `.htaccess` or only on the PHP regex?? in order to work on the PHP regex try: `^p\/(.*)?(.html)$` whitout `RewriteRule` and the  `[R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: Yes I tried it in htaccess and it still goes to page 404, even clearing the cache

Comment: But does it redirect properly to the `domain.com/example-title`?

Comment: I believe something is wrong on your URL structure, see `.htaccess` working test: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=872dd942-2e9f-5be9-a641-cc89a613436f

Comment: Not redirecting, I edited my question, see how the htaccess is

Comment: Alright, you are using Wordpress then... See, detailed questions gives your more detailed answers... See my updated answer...